# What are my options with local databases?

Tags: c#, database

I am creating a C# WPF application and I would like to use a local database to store data, however I am utterly confused on what to use. 
I wont be storing any huge data and I would like to be able to run the application without having to install any other software (Like SQL server). I looked around but found it hard to find relevant information.
I thought about using SQL server compact edition but it appears that it is not supported, it also appears that I am unable to create a .sdf database in VS2015 community, .mdf database being the only option (which I assume requires an SQL server).

> SQL Server compact edition is in deprecation mode with no new releases planned near future. Last release SQL CE 4.0SP1 (and earlier releases that are still in the support cycle) will continue to be supported through its life cycle and Microsoft is committed to fix any major, production blocking issues found in these releases.

Could you state what are my options on what I can use or reference me somewhere where I can read something about this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure what data you're thinking about storing but if you want to keep it simple you could simply serialize an object to a file in JSON format for example. Another option is an object database instead of going the SQL route. No need for an extra ORM library in those cases.NDatabase and Perst seem like good options (haven't used them). db4o seems to be no longer active. SQLite has been around for a while though so I bet it's robust as hell and will fit your needs. Even with that you can use it as a simple store for JSON objects and skip the ORM layer altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the most widely used solutions is [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/). It's a tiny but powerful enough embedded SQL engine and it's cross-platform. It exists since a long time and it has an [ADO.NET driver](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki).

Answer (score 0):

Go with [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/). We have been using it a lot. It is fast and robust, for such a use-case, and can be accessed by many languages. Unlike regular databases, it does not require an extra process, and it results in a file that you can later copy around.

Answer (score 0):

You will go with the combination of a light-ORM and SQLite. It will satisfy all your needs and beyond.

For a specific light-ORM i emphasize on using [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net)

Open your Visual Studio add sqlite and dapper.

Here is an example of a simple Data Access Layer using dapper

```
public class MyDal
{
    public List<string> GetSomething()
    {
        var strQuery = string.Format(SQLCOMMAND);
        var result = new List<String>();
        using (var con = DbConnection())
        {
            result = con.Query<String>(strQuery).ToList();
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static OleDbConnection DbConnection()
    {
        return new OleDbConnection(myConnectionString);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use SQLite.
Add SQLite dll's into your project references through nuget package installer.
Example basic CRUD Operations using SQLite C#.

```
 public class DownloadDatabase
{
    SQLiteConnection sqliteConnection;
    public DownloadDatabase(string dbName)
    {
        string ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + "Absoute path to database store location" + ";Version=3;";
        sqliteConnection = new SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString);
        sqliteConnection.Open();
    }

    public void CreateDB()
    {
        string table = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Downloads ( _id INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY NULL,user_id TEXT  NULL DEFAULT '', target_id TEXT NOT NULL, url TEXT NOT NULL, local_file TEXT NOT NULL,authenticate TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '', login TEXT NULL DEFAULT '', password TEXT NULL DEFAULT '', mime_type TEXT NULL DEFAULT '', accept_ranges TEXT NULL DEFAULT '', file_size NUMBER NULL DEFAULT 0, last_modified TEXT NULL DEFAULT '',created TEXT NULL DEFAULT '',initial_start_position NUMBER NULL DEFAULT 0, start_position NUMBER NULL DEFAULT 0, end_position NUMBER NULL DEFAULT 0, progress TEXT NOT NULL,is_paused TEXT NULL ,device_id TEXT NULL, state NUMBER NULL, originID TEXT NULL DEFAULT '');";
        try
        {
            using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(table, sqliteConnection))
            {
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Creating Downloads database failed: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public void UpdateDBAndCreateEntryIfNotExists(DownloadItem item)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SQLiteCommand checkEntryCommand = sqliteConnection.CreateCommand())
            {
                checkEntryCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Downloads WHERE target_id=@target_id LIMIT 1";
                checkEntryCommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@target_id", item.targetID));
                using (SQLiteDataReader reader = checkEntryCommand.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader.Read())
                    {
                        using (SQLiteCommand updatecommand = sqliteConnection.CreateCommand())
                        {
                            double dprogress;
                            if (!Double.TryParse(reader.GetString(16), out dprogress))
                            {
                                dprogress = 0;
                            }
                            if (item.progress != dprogress)
                            {
                                updatecommand.CommandText = "UPDATE Downloads SET last_modified=@last_modified, start_position=@start_position, end_position=@end_position, progress = @progress, is_paused = @is_paused, state = @state WHERE target_id=@target_id";
                                updatecommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@last_modified", item.lastModified));
                                updatecommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@start_position", item.startPosition));
                                updatecommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@end_position", item.endPosition));
                                updatecommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@progress", item.progress));
                                updatecommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@target_id", item.targetID));
                                updatecommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@is_paused", item.isPaused ? "True" : "False"));
                                updatecommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@state", item.state));
                                updatecommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        using (SQLiteCommand insertcommand = sqliteConnection.CreateCommand())
                        {
                            insertcommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Downloads ( target_id, url,local_file, authenticate, login, password, mime_type, accept_ranges, file_size, last_modified, created, initial_start_position, start_position, end_position, progress, is_paused, device_id, state, originID)  values (@target_id,@url, @local_file, @authenticate,@login,@password,@mime_type,@accept_ranges,@file_size, @last_modified,@created, @initial_start_position,@start_position,@end_position,@progress,@is_paused, @device_id, @state, @originID) ";
                            insertcommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@target_id", item.targetID));
                            insertcommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@url", item.url));
                            insertcommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@local_file", item.localFile));
                            insertcommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@authenticate", item.authenticate));
                            insertcommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@login", item.login == null ? "" : item.login));
                            insertcommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@password", item.password == null ? "" : item.password));
                            insertcommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@mime_type", item.mimeType));
                            insertcommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@accept_ranges", item.acceptRanges));
                            insertcommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@file_size", item.fileSize));
                            insertcommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@last_modified", item.lastModified));
                            insertcommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@created", item.created));
                            insertcommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@initial_start_position", item.initialStartPosition));
                            insertcommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@start_position", item.startPosition));
                            insertcommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@end_position", item.endPosition));
                            insertcommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@progress", item.progress));
                            insertcommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@is_paused", item.isPaused ? "True" : "False"));
                            insertcommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@device_id", item.deviceId == null ? "" : item.deviceId));
                            insertcommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@state", item.state));
                            insertcommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@originID", item.originID));
                            insertcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Download progress update failed: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public bool DeleteItem(string targetID)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SQLiteCommand deleteCommand = sqliteConnection.CreateCommand())
            {
                string tableName = "";
                tableName = "Downloads";
                deleteCommand.CommandText = "DELETE FROM " + tableName + " WHERE target_id=@target_id";
                deleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@target_id", targetID));
                deleteCommand.ExecuteReader();
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Delete item Failed: " + ex.Message);
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution that I have repeatedly used with success in such situations is not using any DBMS. Instead you can use ADO.NET's `DataSet` to directly read from and write to a disk file. A few benefits of this approach:

1. They can serialize their structure and data with single line calls.
2. No drivers/libraries needed. DataSets have always been supported in .NET out of the box.
3. No SQL needed. Perform filtering/sorting etc. using LINQ or data controls.
4. Strongly typed DataSets give you intellisense support.

A few disadvantages:

1. No SQL support. If you need complex querying, this approach might not work.
2. Inappropriate for large data because the entire DB will be loaded into memory at once.

Since you have explicitly mentioned that you need a small, local database, these issues might not hurt you.

Answer (score 0):

You have lots of options, but also consider your long-term needs:

- Using xml, simply serialize/deserialize your objects to local xml files.
- Similarly, serialize to a json format - it's more compact and still human readable.
- Instead of *installing* a database, rent a cloud-provided one like MySQL. A developer account should be free as long as your data is small. Use a relational ORM like Entity Framework as middleware, so you can easily try out different databases. EF6 works with Firebird, which understands xml files (if you go with the first option)
- Skip relational databases altogether and go with a OODB like NDatabase. You should be able to find that in the cloud too.